# can we call action function of a reducer from another reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i am trying to call a reducer function from another reducer function.
but i get error 'redux.js:283 Uncaught Error: Reducers may not dispatch actions.'
this is my counter reducer:

```
const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
        console.log("increment counter",state)
        store.dispatch({ type: "SIGN_IN", payload: 'new data' })
        return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
        return state.count - 1;
    case "RESET":
        return (state.count = 0 );
    default:
        return state.count;
}
};
```

this is my logger reducer:

```
const loggedReducer = (state=false, action) =>{


switch(action.type){
      case 'SIGN_IN':
          console.log("SIGN_IN")
          return !state;
      default:
          return state;
  }
}
```

im trying to dispatch "SIGN_IN" action from "INCREMENT" action.
is it possible or not?

Comment: yes this fixed my problem thanks.
but i want to ask that instead of using redux-thunk, can not we directly dispatch action from other reducer actions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Redux, it's generally not recommended for a reducer to directly dispatch actions. Reducers should be pure functions that take the current state and an action as input and return a new state based on the action's type and payload.

The error you're encountering, "Reducers may not dispatch actions," is a result of trying to dispatch an action directly within a reducer. Instead of dispatching actions from within a reducer, you should dispatch actions from your components or other parts of your application that interact with the store.

In your case, you want to dispatch the "SIGN_IN" action from the "INCREMENT" action. To achieve this, you can dispatch the "SIGN_IN" action in the component or function where you handle the "INCREMENT" action, not within the "counterReducer" itself. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
  import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

  const YourComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    // Dispatch the INCREMENT action
    dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' });

    // Dispatch the SIGN_IN action
    dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', payload: 'new data' });
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So we can not directly dispatch actions from reducers?

Comment: In Redux, it's not recommended to dispatch actions directly from reducers. Reducers should only update the state based on the actions they receive. Actions should be dispatched from other parts of your application, such as components or middleware.

Comment: More specifically: you _cannot ever_ dispatch an action from inside of a reducer.  The store will throw an error if you try to do that.